# Outlook Addin with React - Issue with React routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, outlook, react-router, npm-install

I am trying to develop an Outlook addin which will fetch all the attachments from the email chain and perform some actions on them.

I am new to react and outlook add in too.

I want to perform navigation from Home page to other page using react routing.

I have added the appropariate npm packages for React router. (react-router)

When I am trying to navigate fro home page to other page it gives me an error as listed below:

> A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the
>   actual error object in development.

**Note:** I am using Outlook addin as Yoman office generator, which generates files with .tsx extension.

The same code seems to work on `.js` file.

Let me know if you require more information for this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Could you include the relevant code in the question?

Answer (score -1):

I am able to resolve it myself, actually missing one typescript definitions for the routing file.

i have installed the dependencies react-router-dom by missed the typescript definitions for it which is as:

> npm install @types/react-router-dom --save-dev

Thanks